# dating photos by size of print

Tags: date, forensics, old-prints

I have hundreds of photos I'd like to assign a year to and I am hoping to find a chart that would contain the year span prints were developed based on the size of the print such as 2 1/2 x 4 1/4, 3 1/4 x 4 1/4 or 4 x 5 in prints?

Using clothing styles doesn't work since I have 12 uncles and the clothes were handed down from cousin to cousin

Another chart or site that would be helpful would be one that includes the type of border on the front of the print; both white borders and designed borders

Comment: How precisely do you want to date with them? Do you have have a range of dates?

Comment: Well if clothes were handed down, then you know how to sort them based on the apparent ages of the people wearing the same clothes. If you have two photos of 5 year olds in the same dress, then you know which one was taken first. next use DOB to be more precise.

Comment: I appreciate the comments on using clothes, however that is not really helpful, and as far as the range of dates, that is what I am trying to determine, which is why I thought print size combined with border might help shrink the range of dates.

Answer (score 2):

Using the print size or border style seems like a long shot to me. That could be influenced by film brand, paper brand, chosen print lab and country, let alone time frame. If you do get a time frame, you're more likely to get a decade than a year. That said, antiques or forensics experts may be able to guide you.

Comment: Right, there has always been many sizes of prints.  It's not realistic to imagine it defining an age.   Even color vs B&W is not failsafe.  But it might be reasonable to imagine borderless prints are this century, instead of last century.